# How to configure JPA to use JNDI?

Tags: jpa, persistence, jndi

I have a working persistence definition that works on java level tests. Now I want to incorporate that into a web application which defines the database connection as JNDI in the context.xml. What do I need to change to make it work with the JNDI instead of the persistence.xml or at least get the infor from there?

Comment: Did you manage to do it?

Comment: Yes but my answer with the details got deleted for no good reason. It comes down to use JTA datasources. See this http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/configuration.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *persistence.xml* beginning should be something like this (using *EclipseLink* as implementation), for a *jdbc/MYNAME* JNDI name:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">    
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/MYNAME</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>org.test.entity.MyEntity</class>
...
  </persistence-unit>
<persistence>
```

Of course you should set the configuration suitable for your environment. In the example I use a non-JTA *DataSource*: according to one of your comments, it seems your *DataSource* is not JTA-compliant. For *Hibernate*, the persistence provider should be different.

Answer (score 0):

you must use the persistence.xml when you're using JPA. because JPA must check the persistence.xml. so you can use persistence.xml and jndi at the same time.